# Remove extra space in text file

Tags: vb.net, excel, notepad

I am creating a text file and copying some pre-generated Excel data into it. It is working fine. But the output is like the following:

```
MGSSP:IMSI= 40211xxxx   ;
MGSSP:IMSI= 40211xxxx   ;
MGSSP:IMSI= 40211xxxx   ;
...
```

I want to get rid of the blank spaces after the `=` and before the `;`. That is the desire output should be like:

```
MGSSP:IMSI=40211xxxx;
MGSSP:IMSI=40211xxxx;
MGSSP:IMSI=40211xxxx;
...
```

I am using the following code:

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Temp\mgssp_script.txt") Then
        Dim proc As Process = Process.Start("notepad.exe", "C:\Temp\mgssp_script.txt")
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250)
        SendKeys.Send("^v")
    Else
        Dim file As System.IO.FileStream
        file = System.IO.File.Create("C:\Temp\mgssp_script.txt")
        file.Close()
        Dim proc As Process = Process.Start("notepad.exe", "C:\Temp\mgssp_script.txt")
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250)
        SendKeys.Send("^V")
        file.Close()
    End If
```

Comment: Why do you close the file twice? Also, why do you need to rely on notepad to do the work for you? get the data from the clipboard into your program and manipulate it in your code, then save it to the text file using `File.AppendAllText` method.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: I agree that file.close() is not needed twice. Will remove the first instance. I have the data in clipboard but am not sure how to modify the data before pasting in notepad. Could you help me code it?

Comment: Actually, you should remove the second call, not the first one. Do you need the notepad to open, or are you just using it to save the file?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: I need notepad to open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the clipboard data into your program using the `Clipboard` class in `System.Windows.Forms` namespace.

If this is not a winforms application, you will have to add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` and include an `Imports` statement for it in your code: `Imports System.Windows.Forms`.
Also, my code uses the `RegEx` class in `System.Text.RegularExpressions` so you will have to import that as well.

This code will get the clipboard data into your program, replace the spaces, and set the changed string back to the clipboard.

```
Dim ClipBoardlData As String
If Clipboard.ContainsText() Then
    ClipBoardlData = Clipboard.GetText()
    Dim re As Regex =  New Regex("=\s+") ' for the = and spaces after it
    ClipBoardlData = re.Replace(ClipBoardlData, "=")
    re = New Regex("\s+;") ' for the spaces before the ;
    ClipBoardlData = re.Replace(ClipBoardlData, ";") 
    Clipboard.SetText(ClipBoardlData)
End If
```

after that you can keep using the code you have to open the notepad application.

Comment: tried your code. The output which I got had the space after the `=` sign. the space before `;` is fixed alright. When I am looking into it closely, the space after `=` looks like 4 spaces but is actually one space when trying to move via arrow keys. It is not a tab either. So that might be cause your code not to find `"= "`.

Comment: Actually, I had a mistake in my first replace: I replaced "= " with " " instead of replacing it with "=". I've edited my answer to fix that.

Comment: Still getting that same space after `=`. When I am copying the excel columns to the notepad, it is showing that text by default.

Comment: Actually I've got it working. Just edited your code a little. 
`ClipBoardlData = ClipBoardlData.Replace("= 4", "=4")`

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to help :-). Please accept the answer so that other people know that the problem is solved. feel free to edit in the changes that you've made that finally solved the problem, or just post your solution on a different answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

A little change in Zohar's code did the trick for me. Here is the code:

```
Dim ClipBoardlData As String
    If Clipboard.ContainsText() Then
        ClipBoardlData = Clipboard.GetText()
        ClipBoardlData = ClipBoardlData.Replace("=  4", "=4") ' Fixed that line.
        Dim re As Regex = New Regex("\s+;")
        ClipBoardlData = re.Replace(ClipBoardlData, ";")
        Clipboard.SetText(ClipBoardlData)
    End If
```